# Remove begining punctuation from a word

Tags: java, regex

I have seen a couple of threads here that kindof matches what I am asking here. But none are concrete. If I have a string like `"New Delhi"`, I want my code to extract `New Delhi`. So here the quotes are stripped off. I want to strip off any punctuation, in general at start and end.

So far, this helps to strip the punctuations at the end:

`String replacedString = replaceable_string.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}*([a-z]+)\\p{Punct}*", "$1");`

What am I doing wrong here? My output is  `"New Delhi`  with the beginning quote still there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following will remove a punctuation character from both the beginning and end of a `String` object if present:

```
String s = "\"New, Delhi\"";

// Output: New, Delhi
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("^\\p{Punct}|\\p{Punct}$", ""));
```

The `^` part of the Regex represents the beginning of the text, and `$` represents the end of the text. So, `^\p{Punct}` will match a punctuation that is a first character and `\p{Punct}$` will match a punctuation that is a last character. I used `|` (OR) to match either the first expression or the second one, resulting in `^\p{Punct}|\p{Punct}$`.

In case you want to remove all punctuation characters from the beginning and the end of the `String` object, you can use the following:

```
String s = "\"[{New, Delhi}]\"";

// Output: New, Delhi
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("^\\p{Punct}+|\\p{Punct}+$", ""));
```

I simply added the `+` sign after each `\p{Punct}`. The `+` sign means "One or more", so it will match many punctuations if they are present at the beginning or end of the text.

Hope this is what you were looking for :)

Comment: Best solution. This works for any punctuation. The justification is great as well. Cheers!

Comment: One issue: How can we modify the above to extract these special types of quotes: `code` “My Sweet Valentine” `code`

Comment: You could use the following: `s.replaceAll("^[\\p{Punct}“”]+|[\\p{Punct}“”]+$", "")`. `[` and `]` represent a group of characters, so any character you add in there will be added to the mix.

Comment: I don't know whether these quotes are legible or not. These documents are web documents and contain funny characters. Maybe, I might have to remove any non-alphabetic character from beginning and end of a word. How can we do that? I don't think some are punctuation in my document. If I copy-paste here, it might not be legible.

Comment: You could remove any non-alphanumeric like this:
`s.replaceAll("^[^0-9a-zA-Z]+|[^0-9a-zA-Z]+$", "")`. `^` within `[` and `]` negates the group, making it match everything except the characters it contains.

Comment: In that case this might be useful: `code`String replacedString = replaceable_string.replaceAll("^\\W|\\W$", "");

Comment: Yes or what you wrote :) See, you're beating me at this already

Answer (score 2):

```
class SO {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "\"New Delhi\"";
        String output = "";

        try {
            output = input.replaceAll("(^\\p{P}+)(.+)(\\p{P}+$)", "($1)($2)($3)");
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        }

        System.out.println("Input: " + input);
        System.out.println("Output: " + output);
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Input: "New Delhi"
Output: (")(New Delhi)(")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String replacedString = replacable_string.replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "");
```

or

```
String replacedString = replace_string.replace("\"", "");
```

should work also.

Comment: Thanks. But: Actually, this cannot deal with all kinds of punctuation. Like it cannot extract <code>New Delhi,</code> and keeps the comma at the end. But again thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using this :

```
String data = "\"New Delhi\"";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^\\w\\s]*([\\w\\s]+)[^\\w\\s]*");

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(data);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        // Indicates match is found. Do further processing
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
String s = "\"New Deli\"".replaceAll("\\p{Punct}*(\\P{Punct}+)\\p{Punct}*", "$1");
```

Answer (score -1):

your [a-z] is only going to capture lower case letters and no spaces.  Try ([a-zA-Z ])